# libevent: bufferevent pair gets stuck, no data transfered between inner evbuffer's

Tags: libevent

Context:

I have a bufferevent_pair, let's call them `p0` and `p1`.
Some entity will write into `p0` from time to time and `p1` will read from it's end from time to time (Will not read whenever data is available, i.e. sometimes when the read callback is invoked it will no drain anything from `p1->input`.

I have a read-high-watermark set on the `p1` and I expect that `p0` will hold all data above this watermark and only max. watermark bytes will be transferred into `p1` and whenever the later one is drained, more bytes will be added by libevent into `p1->input` from `p0->input`.

But this doesn't happen, and once I have no more data to write into `p0`, all data that is currently present in `p0->input` will not be transferred into `p1->input` ever, it's stuck there.

Am I doing something that is not expected by libevent? The watermark or the time-to-time reading?
I'm using `event_base_loop(EVLOOP_ONCE | EVLOOP_NONBLOCK)` inside a while. Also I'm triggering the `p1` bufferevent for `EV_READ` once I don't have anything to write and whenever I don't read anything.

I'm expecting libevent to transfer data from `p0->input` into `p1->input` in some way without me having to write more data into `p0->input`